# How do you add a scroll bar to an expander panel?

Tags: wpf

I have a stack panel inside of an expander panel that I programaticaly adds check boxes to.  Currently the exanpander stops at the bottom of the form, but the stack panel keeps growing.  I would like the stack panel to be bounded by the expander and scroll to display the check boxes.  Do I need house the check boxes in a list box to get the scroll functionality?

```
<Grid>
    <Expander Header="Expander1"  Margin="0,0,0,2" Name="Expander1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="Coral">
        <StackPanel Name="StackScroll" Margin="0,0,0,2"  Background="Aqua"></StackPanel>
    </Expander>
</Grid>
```

");

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can nest the StackPanel in a ScrollViewer:

```
  <Grid>  
    <Expander Header="Expander1"  Margin="0,0,0,2" Name="Expander1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="Coral">
      <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <StackPanel Name="StackScroll" Margin="0,0,0,2"  Background="Aqua">
        </StackPanel>
      </ScrollViewer>
    </Expander>
  </Grid>
```

Comment: You could, but the VerticalScrollBarVisibility is an attached property that you can set directly on the StackPanel.

Answer (score 3):

Set **ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"** in your StackPanel declaration.